# Why did the bottom of my stainless steel pan burn during seasoning?

Tags: equipment, stainless-steel

While I was seasoning my stainless steel pan, the bottom turned brown before I added the oil. Why did the bottom of my stainless steel pan burn? Can I remove the stain?

Answer (score 3):

The capacity of the pan to store heat is much smaller than for oil or water. Without anything in the pan, the temperature of the pans surface goes up very high quickly. The color change is done by chemical reaction on the surface, thus removal can be done with chemical reagents and/or scrubbing that effected material off the pan.